# Javascript AJAX call response status 200 OK but error callback is called

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am making this call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    timeout: 20000,
    async: true,
    url: "http://search.carrotsearch.com/carrot2-webapp/search",
    dataType: 'text',
    data: { 
        query:'london',
        results:'100',
        source:'etools',
        algorithm:'lingo3g',
        view:'folders',
        skin:'fancy-compact',
        type:'DOCUMENTS'
    },
    success: function(msg) {
        debugger;
    },
    error: function(err,textStatus, errorThrown){
        debugger;
    }
});
```

`

Fiddler shows response OK 200 and returns correct gzipped contents. But in browser debugger the error callback is called:

[image]

Comment: What's the entire response in the browser's debugging tools?  Is there also any error message on the browser's debugging console?

Comment: can you please try to change the query variable name to something else , and give it a try

Comment: Why the `20000` timeout? o.O

Comment: timeout is irrelevant, the problem exists with/without it.

Comment: David, the browser console does give a hint:Failed to load http://search.carrotsearch.com/carrot2-webapp/search?query=london&results=100&source=etools&algorithm=lingo3g&view=folders&skin=fancy-compact&type=DOCUMENTS&_=1513256030546: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There problem is [`CORS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). `http://search.carrotsearch.com/` doesn't allow AJAX requests.

Look for following error in console.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:XXX' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

It can be that my `localhost` is not listed on `http://search.carrotsearch.com/` server. But, I guess in your case too this is the issue.

Comment: it looks like this error is famous. how do i need to change my code above to make it work? clearly the data is returned from search.carrotsearch.com as i see response in fiddler.

Comment: You cannot do anything on front-end. But you can create a `CORS` enabled backend in nodejs/php or any other framework as a wrapper of this call. Then from `AJAX`, call your `CORS` enabled backend.

Comment: Take a look at this https://codeburst.io/using-nodejs-as-a-proxy-for-angularjs-ajax-requests-8e5e94203e0d